# Writing video on memory OpenCV 2

Tags: c++, opencv

We're currently developing some functionality for our program that needs OpenCV. One of the ideas being tossed at the table is the use of a "buffer" which saves a minute of video data to the memory and then we need to extract like a 13-second video file from that buffer for every event trigger.

Currently we don't have enough experience with OpenCV so we don't know if it is possible or not. Looking at the documentation the only allowable function to write in memory are imencode  and imdecode, but those are images. If we can find a way to write sequences of images to a video file that would be neat, but for now our idea is to use a video buffer.

We're also using OpenCV version 2 specifications.

TL;DR We want to know if it is possible to write a portion of a video to memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenCV, every video is treated as a collection of frames(images). Depending on your cameras' FPS you can capture frames periodically and fill the buffer with them. Meanwhile you can destroy the oldest frame(taken 1 min before). So a FIFO data structure can be implemented to achieve your goal. Getting a 13 second sample is easy, just jump to a random frame and write 13*FPS frames sequentially to a video file.

But there will be some sync and timing problems AFAIK and as far as I've used OpenCV.

[Here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html) is the link of OpenCV documentation about video i/o. Especially the last chunk of code is what you will use for writing.

TL;DR : There is no video, there are sequential images with little differences. So you need to treat them as such.

Comment: Thanks. I thought so, since if there's a video usually there's an infinite while loop to continuously move through the frames. 
It's not really a random 13-second sample, we have some sort of motion detection event and if it's triggered we need to extract a clip 6 seconds before it and 6 seconds after. Really difficult for someone who doesn't really know much.

How do I write in a buffer? Maybe that's for a separate question I guess. For now I guess my idea's possible. Thanks for the answer and the link as well.

Comment: @IBG Creating a buffer and writing to it, is quite trivial. You can come up with it easily.